# How to pass the name of the file to python script when I right click on the file?

Tags: python

I am trying to write a python script for getting subtitles of a file and for that I need to pass the name of the file to python script. Being a beginner at Python I don't know how to do that. 
Can someone help me with that.

It would be of really great help

Comment: right click from what? windows/linux? right click usually does nothing unless you activate a given menu item. please be specific.

Comment: How about showing a dialog asking for the filename?  I'd begin by searching the docs for 'dialog'.

Comment: i am using linux os . When I right click on the file I would like to select the script to run @Jean

Comment: Actually what I want to do is right click on file select the script to run and subtitle to be downloaded just next to the file.  @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Comment: Does your OS have right-click handlers? If so, check into how that works.

Comment: No I am using Linux os and what I mean by right click is that when I right click a menu will appear and I would like to select an option of my script there in the menu and this is how I would pass the name of the file to script . But I don't know how to do that @martineau

Comment: On Windows that menu is called a "context menu". Maybe Linux has something similar. Google is your friend... P.S. You might be able to use "drag-and-drop" instead, where you drag the file with mouse on top of the script.

Comment: Don't know how close Linux is to Ubuntu, but the answer the question [_Is there any tool for creating custom right-click-menu entries, that run Python scripts?_](http://askubuntu.com/questions/653745/is-there-any-tool-for-creating-custom-right-click-menu-entries-that-run-python) looks promising.

Comment: I think I found something that might work @martineau

Comment: Good to hear—now, hopefully, you can answer your own question after a certain amount of time.

Comment: Thanks @martineau it worked finally subtitles are downloading. :)